# TableView has no workspacePath in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, workspace

One of my colleagues is running a script which includes the following Python in ArcMap...

```
oTble = arcpy.mapping.TableView(tbleName)
Workspace = oTble.workspacePath

print "oTble:  '{}'".format(oTble)
if not Workspace:
    print "NULL Workspace!"
    sys.exit()

print "WORKSPACE:  {}".format(Workspace)
```

...and it exits after producing the following output:

```
oTble:  '<geoprocessing Standalone Table object object at 0x2B734A88>'
NULL Workspace!
```

Another colleague runs the same script and it continues on without this problem.

I cannot figure out how a TableView cannot have a NULL workspacePath .

Any ideas how this could happen?

**UPDATE 1:**

I have created a new MXD, and added the table to this new MXD.  It works fine there.  If I delete ALL layers and tables from the original MXD, and then add the table back into the original MXD in the same way as I did for the new MXD, it still fails.

**UPDATE 2:**

Based on the suggestion in comments, I've added the following code for debugging purposes...

```
d = arcpy.Describe(oTble)
print d.baseName
print d.catalogPath
```

This outputs (actual values modified to protect the innocent):

```
SDE_DBName.GISADMIN
\SDE_DBName.GISADMIN.TableName
```

This does not include the workspace in it anywhere.

If I run the same on a new blank document after adding in the relevant table, I get:

```
SDE_DBName.GISADMIN.TableName
\\host\Connections\ConnectionFileName.sde\SDE_DBName.GISADMIN.TableName
```

Comment: The table will have no workspace path if the table is *in* arcpy.env.workspace

Comment: It is not in arcpy.env.workspace.

Comment: What is the value of tbleName? To open a table by *name only* it must be in the environ workspace, unless the table type does not support IWorkspace. Try d = arcpy.Describe(oTble) then Workspace = d.catalogPath[:len(d.baseName)-1] and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Michael.  See update 2, above.